# "Building" content of the page using Github Pages

Tags: web-hosting, github, static-content

**Prelude**

I have a simple daemon service that generates data (in plain text) and then a script pushes it to repo. This data is needed to generate graphs for time periods.

**Requirement**

I don't have/can't afford some dedicated hosting so I want to try using something like GitHub Pages for this. I know it is for static  content only but I was wondering if there is a way for it to work.

**Question itself**

I have the data in a form of plan-text files and I need to build graph out of each piece of data (per day/month). The easiest way would be use classic method to pre-process the data and just generate the html, like via some python framework or whatever but I was wondering if there is way to something integrate with with GH, in a sense that I just push my data file into `data/` on the branch and then setup build pipelien and site logic does the rest. The readme for Github Actions is talking about web-site building pipeline, however, because it is not aimed at newbies it is **hard for me to put it in a context** I understand. Can I somehow push some kind of build template (with my logic) for Github it later can use to build and generate output html? Or perhaps there is a way to publish some small SPA framework whatever that can generate graphs from the files on the fly?

I know it is a very broad question on the basic topic and I did my google-fu but a lot of supposed begging how-to assume some kind of basic knowledge/basis.

Comment: I don't think that this question belongs here, as it is not about running a web (or mail) server you own/control, nor is it SEO related.  I'm not sure where it does belong - MAYBE superuser.com but more likely devops.stackexchange.com (which I'd not even heard of till now!)

Comment: I am not sure if you can do this purely in github actions but you can do what you describe in a static site generator such as Jekyll on Github pages. https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/